# Tradução com género incorrecto na janela de sinalizações para comentários

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, comentários, flags

A janela para indicar o tipo de sinalização parece-me ter o género incorrecto:

[image: Captura de Tela]

Estamos a referir-nos a um comentário (masculino), pelo que deveria aparecer:

- rude ou ofensivo
- não construtivo
- obsoleto
- extenso demais
- outro...

Onde ao realizarmos a leitura de toda a frase ficaria:

- Sinalizo este comentário como **rude ou ofensivo**
- Sinalizo este comentário como **não construtivo**
- Sinalizo este comentário como **obsoleto**
- Sinalizo este comentário como **extenso demais**
- Sinalizo este comentário como **outro...**